# How to get how many seconds are left before session expiration django

Tags: django, django-sessions

In Django I can set the expiration time for the session

```
request.session.set_expiry(300)
```

and after 5 minutes the session ends.

When a user makes a request for a view, I want to be able to check how many seconds are left in the current session before it expires.
The following method

```
request.session.get_expiry_age()
```

is returning 300 instead of the seconds left.

Is there anyway to get the seconds left in a session before it expires?

Comment: Are you calling get_expiry_date in view? Because session expiration time is reset in SessionMiddleware which is called before your view, so 300 would be correct expiry_date

Comment: Yes I'm calling it in view, if I create my own middleware and call it there will the value be the seconds the session has left?

Comment: It should be, if your middleware will be called before SessionMiddleware

Comment: OK, but If I do 2 requests, will the second request get the right value? Because after the first request, the session middleware has already changed the value.

Comment: Damm, just looked at SessionMiddleware documentation and looks like I have been wrong, it's not changing with every request unless you specify that in settting. Please refer to [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1371117/16494437)

Comment: I have already seen that question, but that is not my problem. On that question, OP wants to set_expiry(300) every time the user makes a request, and is not a good practice to make it on every view, so they gave him a solution to do it on middleware or to use SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST. I don't want that, I just want to know how many time the user has left on the current session.